# Upgrade apk downloaded from own web server

Tags: android

I need help in upgrading apk file. I have apk file developed for android 2.2 and I donot wish to publish my apk on android market. I published apk in our own webserver. And i could download it to my android mobile. Now the issue is that how can i upgrade apk file by publishing in our webserver.

My questions are:

1. How android market does apk upgrading?
2. How to upgrade a binary in android mobile with new version of which old version is already installed?
3. I used android built in view using intent which actually Re-installs apk not upgrading.But i don't want prompts asking "Do u want to install application?".

I want the apk to be upgraded once user click upgrade button without showing prompt to user, like doing in android market.

1. Is there any method to upgrade apk in android?
2. Are there any restrictions doing that?
3. Are there any specific permissions i need or i need to set in manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are publishing an App on your private web server, you need to create a process through which you can check for new version .There is **No in built method** for doing this .

I have created one as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I could check the installed version with the new version. And how do you update application? Will update happen directly from webserver? Or You download the app from webserver to sdcard and then u do upgrade? if so u do actual upgrade of installed app or u just replace the installed app with the new app using built in andriod intents.I just want to know how android market does apk upgrade without user prompt and directly from the market site? Should my phone be rooted for doing like that? If so how android market does in my unrooted phone?

Comment: Please do not use youtube language on this site Mohit, it looks terribly unprofessional.

Comment: Not actually.but thanx i followed your idea and i hosted my own web browser and created a process for checking new version.When new it is installed, it seems to be installing a new app not upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've downloaded the APK, Android itself decides if the program is installed and needs to be upgraded, or if it is a new installation. Users can decide for themselves whether to upgrade or not.

Answer (score 2):

Besides how to find out when there is an update available, it's not possible to upgrade it without prompting the user with the "Do you want to install". Android doesn't allow third apps to install apps unless the phone is rooted and your app has root access, but I think that this isn't your target group.

I have no experience with that but what you could try is loading classes manually from your server and then store it in the assets folder.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

This is one approach, I don't think that it's very handy and easy but it would work.

Hope it helps!

PS:
*And just because I'm wondering, is there a reason why don't you wanna publish it on the Android Market?*

Comment: I have concern which has small no of customers. For these numbers i donot want to publish my on android market. I read in android documentation that we can also have our own webserver to host and upgrade our app.And not all the people publish only through android market. So how do they upgrade their app after publishing on their own webserver?