# How to update android app automatically without Google Play or user interaction

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk, android-update-app

I'm developping an application that will run on a tablet device in a store (e.g. restaurant). The device does not have Google Play and is rooted. How do I install an update to my application automatically, with absolutelly NO user interaction?

To clarify, checking for a new version of APK hosted on my server and downloading it are not part of this question, only the "silent" update part is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upgrade apk downloaded from own web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923643/upgrade-apk-downloaded-from-own-web-server)

Comment: Have you not seen this in your searches? https://github.com/lazydroid/auto-update-apk-client

Comment: ^The solution provided on that link requires user interaction.

Comment: Right, and it's an OS security flaw not to require interaction for upgrading rouge apps. You're in an environment where it shouldn't be hard to update nightly / weekly IMO

Comment: As android is quite security conscious I am not sure it is possible to update without user interaction. You would need at least a user to press a button to authorize update, the app itself can search and download updates without user interaction - but cannot install !

Comment: My second link has a `SilentAutoUpdate`. Maybe it does what you want

Comment: @ChickenFeet I have found answers stating that it is not possible unless rooted, which my device is. However, none of those answers specify how to do it when rooted...

Comment: Perhaps you can design you app to download a file that includes the necessary updates, depending on what kind of update the app requires - if it is for a restaurant and you only need to make menu changes this could work. 
Sorry if this isn't the answer you're looking for. Keep searching!! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your device needs to be rooted. It seems this is already done for you. Now all you have to do is to make your application check if a new version of the APK is available. If so, launch a service in background to download the required APK and run this code to silently install it.

```
public static void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

You can basically modify the ABD command to perform whatever you want. Please note that a rooted device can be dangerous and cause security breach.